# Can moderators intervene if an answer isn't upvoted or accepted?

Tags: discussion, support

Can I raise a flag to moderator to intervene when one hasn't the upvoted or accepted an answer but has verbally communicated it in the comments section?

Comment: What are you expecting the Moderator to do?

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Is the answer given in a comment or did you write an answer that got an approval comment from the OP but your answer didn't receive an upvote and/or was accepted.

Comment: I gave an answer , which wasn't upvoted or accepted by the asker. Though he verbally thanked me for the answer and has a good reputation in the community , so he kind of knows how stack overflow works

Comment: No, you can't use a moderator flag for that. How users vote and if they accept an answer is their decision. No moderator is going to change that.

Comment: Often, this happens with people new to the site. In such cases, I sometimes @ their name, say "You're welcome. Since you're new to the site..." and explain why and how to mark answers as well as up- and downvote. Very politely! If they do, I delete my comment.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear: **Moderators cannot change accept marks**. Full stop. Not only wouldn't we want to do this, there is **no functionality that enables us to do so**.

Comment: Thanks everyone ! I totally understand.

Answer (score 10):

No. This is not something that requires a moderator flag.

Just ask the commenter if they want to post their comment as an answer. If, after some time (perhaps a few workdays) they haven't, then you can post it as an answer yourself. You could make it Community Wiki, to show that you're not out to "steal" rep. Also, a link to the comment would be appropriate, giving credit to the user who actually supplied the information.

Comment: You should have written this as a comment and given the OP the opportunity to put this suggestion into practise!